# Having difficulty using validates_uniqueness_of with a specific condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, validates-uniqueness-of

My model, `Goal`, has these three attributes: `goal_type`, `goal_length`, and `is_complete`.
`Goal` `belongs_to :user`.

`goal_type` can only be "X", "Y", or "Z"

`goal_length` can only be "short", "mid", or "long"

`is_complete` can be true or false

I want there to only ever be one `Goal` (`validates_uniqueness_of`) with a specified `goal_length` and `goal_type` when looking at Goals that both belong to the same user and have is_complete set to false

Plain english examples:

If a user has a `short` `X` goal that they have not yet completed, they cannot create a new `short` `X` goal.
If a user has a `short` `X` goal that they have completed, they can create a new `short` `X` goal.

**This validation works, but does not check if the existing goals have their `is_complete` attribute set to true.  If `is_complete` is true on the previously existing models, it is ok to create a new goal with the same attributes:**

```
validates_uniqueness_of :goal_type, scope: [:goal_length, :user_id]
```

How would I add a check for the condition where the validation is ignored if the matching previous goal has is_complete set to true ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This validation appears to work as expected:

```
validates_uniqueness_of :goal_type, scope: [:goal_length, :user_id],  conditions: -> { where(is_complete: false) }
```